# Filtering Data on VARCHAR data type

Tags: oracle, query

I have a column. The data type is VARCHAR2. What I am trying to do is write a query to catch only the records that contain a string either in the beginning or end or in the middle. Below is a sample.

```
Column1
AB786GH
7890651
387A656
723068X
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... in the beginning or end or in the middle

Basically, *anywhere*.

There are various ways you could do that, e.g. using `instr` function which returns a positive number (position of the string you're searching for):

```
SQL> with test (column1) as
  2    (select 'AB786GH' from dual union all
  3     select '7890651' from dual union all
  4     select '387A656' from dual union all
  5     select '723068X' from dual
  6    )
  7  select column1
  8  from test
  9  where instr(column1, '78') > 0;

COLUMN1
-------
AB786GH
7890651
```

Or, as Wernfried commented, `like` operator:

```
<snip>
  7  select column1
  8  from test
  9  where column1 like '%78%';

COLUMN1
-------
AB786GH
7890651
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your valuable Answers

It is Benn resolved by the below query :

Select * from table1 where regex_like(column_name,'[[:alpha:]]');